# Do Eidolons need proficiency feats to benefit from armor?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner

In order to let my eidolons wear armor, I would have to take the required feats, correct? For example, if I custom made plate mail for my large Behir, he would need to take light, medium, and heavy armor proficiencies?

I ask because I thought you could armor a war horse with custom made armor, and they are incapable of taking feats of their own. Need to be sure before I dump a lot of coin in something that can't immediately be used.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Eidolons cannot wear armor even after taking proficiency feats.

From the d20pfsrd website:

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons

> Armor Bonus
>
> The number noted here is the eidolon’s base total armor bonus. This
>   bonus may be split between an armor bonus and a natural armor bonus,
>   as decided by the summoner. This number is modified by the eidolon’s
>   base form and some options available through its evolution pool. **An
>   eidolon cannot wear armor of any kind, as the armor interferes with
>   the summoner’s connection to the eidolon.**